# What if a feature fully available for training is not fully available in test instances?

Tags: feature-selection, model

In training a model, I know that there exists a feature that is fully available during training, but will be available only in 15% of test instances when the model is deployed. How to handle this issue? Is it possible to learn a better model?

Comment: Is the feature strongly informative of the outcome? If not, you could just exclude it entirely. Is it missing at random? If so, you could use [tag:imputation].

Comment: Is the feature "missing-at-random"? In other words, does the presence or absence of the feature tell you anything about the response, or about the other features? Or is it just completely random which observations include that feature and which don't?

Comment: Yes, the feature is missing at random. In the deployment, the feature is hard to capture for some reasons so that some test instances have this feature but others don't. The presence or absence of the feature doesn't imply anything on the outcome or other features.

Comment: Just a note, I think you all are saying missing at random when you really mean missing completely at random. Missing at random implies the missingness is related to some observed variables